# using session in while loop

Tags: php, session-variables

I am attempting to store the ID number in session and send it to another page however it will not store the variable and it comes as undefined

```
session_start();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
   {
      <tr>
         <td><a href=notes.php? $_SESSION["ID"]= $row["ID"] ?><?php echo $row["ID"]?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["staffName"] ?></td>
      </tr>
   }
```

EDIT: In the database there are many ID's and session is only storing the last one with this code. How can I do it that the ID pressed is the one stored?

Comment: where you are getting the session variable in which line you getting the error

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're starting your session before any output is put on the screen otherwise it'll never create a usable session.

For example this won't work, because the headers have already been sent to the browser without a session id.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = 1;

?>
</head>
<body>
  ... content ...
</body>
```

This however WILL work, assuming this is the start of your code execution as the headers won't be sent with your session id until the first character is outputted to the browser.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = 1;

?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  ... content ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to store like this,

```
<?php $_SESSION["ID"] =  $row["ID"]; ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php $_SESSION["ID"] = ID; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $_SESSION["ID"] = $row["ID"]; ?>
```